# Numeric scalebars don't (always) update when changing the map's extent in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-print-layouts, scale-bar

If you change your map's extent but maintain the scale in a QGIS Layout, the scalebar's width will be updated proportionally with the CRS's distortion for the new extent. E.g. if your map (crs 3857) is focussing on the equator, and you drag the map's extent to the north (maintaining the same scale), the scalebar's width will enlarge automatically, which is good, because in pseudomercator areas around the equator are displayed relatively smaller than areas futher away from the equator.
However, if you do the same thing while having a 'numeric' scalebar, the scale is not updated in the same way. Why is that?

And how come, if you do the same thing while your map has a geographic CRS such as WGS84 (4326), the numeric scale will be updated just like the scalebars are?

[image: Scale: 1:5000000, CRS:3857, focus: equator]

[image: Scale: 1:5000000, CRS:3857, focus: equator | Bigger scalebar, but same numeric scale]

Comment: Have you made sure your numeric scale is correctly linked to the map?

Comment: Yes, I did link the numeric scale to the map (Scalebar item properties > Main Properties > Map)

Comment: EPSG:3857 may be useful for visualising data but it should not be used were you wish to do GIS-like things such as measuring distances or areas, because of scale-error. Try Googling something like "EPSG:3857 scale errors" for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You're completely right EPSG:3857 isn't a good crs for these kind of measurements! I did use it in my question above primarily to accentuate what I was trying to ask. The same thing happens (although way less clear) when using other systems (e.g. EPSG:3035 for Europe, EPSG:28992 for the Netherlands): when changing the map's content, the scalebar's width changes (albeit often less than a mm), but the numeric scale stays the same. I guess in all these cases scale-errors will be the cause, but I was wondering why bars are treated differently than numeric scales.